# how to configure Jetspeed user password validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, passwords

We need to enable password validation through jetspeed configuration to be applied when logging to jetpseed portal or when changing the user password. In Jetspeed documentation: https://portals.apache.org/jetspeed-2/deployguide/security-config.html they mentioned that a configuration file security-spi-atn.xml should be updated. However, while updating this file, either nothing change, or some class not found exceptions are thrown although the needed jar is present. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that Jetspeed 2.3.0 had several bugs and we had to contact apache team to fix these issues.

Comment: Do you have an idea in which version this will be fixed ?

Comment: Apache support team sent me the jar containing some fixes but i am not sure in what version they will release them. Probably in 2.3.3...

Comment: Can you share this jar with me? if no it's ok I contact Apache support. Thank you